# Custom Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have got the following three tables (just an example)

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Code> Codes { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Code> Codes { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int entity_id { get; set; }
    public string entity_type { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Now a code can either belong to a User or a Device, which will be determined by the value of entity_type (i.e. 'user' or 'device'). How can this be achieved in Entity Framework ?

Comment: Use two nullable columns, one for a user id and another for the device id, and add validation to require one of them not be null.

Comment: *How can this be achieved in Entity Framework ?* Simply it can't

Comment: The logic is good, will it provoque errors ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Table per Hierarchy (TPH) solution using the entity_type as the discriminator?

Comment: @David, looks like Table per Hierarchy (TPH) is the perfect solution to my problem. Couldn't have found it if it wasn't for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change your Code class to

```
public class Code
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Device device { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

This way one of those properties can be null.

Hope it helps.

The drawback is that you could have a code that have a user an a device